# menu with absolute/fixed position: when scrolling menu to much, the parent should scroll

Tags: html, css, layout, fixed, absolute

Sorry for the title, not sure how to describe my problem shortly.

I have a basic HTML structure like that:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="article">article</div>
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
</div>
```

The

- The article is on the left, and the menu on the right.
- The both the article and the menu can have many innercontent, and both can be scrolled.
- The menu should be fixed: scrolling the article at the very bottom should not make the menu disappear from the screen
- The scrollbar to scroll the article should be at the very right of the screen (like a scrollbar on `body`, so basically the scrollbar should be on the `container` element and not on the `article`)
- If the menu is not scrollable, or is "scrolled too much", scrolling on it should trigger the scrolling of the article.

In this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnw76ffw/1/) attempt, you can see that when we scroll on the menu, once we reach the bottom and continue scrolling, it makes the article (actually the container) scroll: it is what I want. The problem is that when I scroll the article (ie the container), the menu is not fixed and will move out of the screen too.

Now check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnw76ffw/2/) of another attempt with a menu with `position: absolute;`. This time the menu does not scroll with the content (as wanted) but in this case when "scrolling too much" the menu, it does not start scrolling the article. Maybe it will be more clear in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnw76ffw/4/) with a menu not scrollable: we can't scroll the article when the mouse is on top of the menu.

Note I can't use `pointer-events: none;` on the menu, because obviously it contains buttons.

Comment: Do you want this in a div, or does "container" represent the screen/window?

Comment: I want this on a div, my container is not `body`. The scrollbar to scroll the article should be at the right of the container (and not at the right of body)